# Jquery: Doing an interval, timout, then interval again

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I'm trying to do a reveal of a list of elements 1 after another in a setInterval for 5 seconds but after the 7th element, i want to wait for 60 seconds, meaning a timeout and continue the interval.

Following is my code, I can get it done but the problem with this code is that it does the timeout repetatively on every 7th element, however, i'm only looking to do it on the 1st 7th occurance and not on all the 7th element.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var index=0;
        var firstInterval=setInterval(function(){
            if(index==7){
                $("#love p:hidden:first").fadeIn(2000);
                clearInterval(firstInterval);
                index=0;
                return;
            }else{
                $("#love p:hidden:first").fadeIn(2000);
                index++;
            }
            var timeout=setTimeout(function(){
                $("#love p:hidden:first").fadeIn(2000);
                var secondInterval=setInterval(function(){
                    $("#love p.2nd_batch:hidden:first").fadeIn(2000);
                },5000);
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            },60000);
        },5000);
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: I don't think there is any reason you should ``clearTimeout(timeout);`` as timeout's only happen once.

Comment: I also think, moving your ``var timeout = ...`` into your first if statement, may fix your problem.

Comment: Could you supply a bit of html?

Comment: I'm sorry. Its on the 2nd occurrance of the 7th element that the whole process stop but I need it to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/301hsmom/3/ (watch the bottom right)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var index = 1;
  var firstInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (index === 7) {
      $("#love p").filter(":hidden").filter(":first").fadeIn(2000);
      clearInterval(firstInterval);
      index = 1;
      var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $("#love p:hidden:first").fadeIn(2000);
        var secondInterval = setInterval(function() {
          var elem = $("#love p").filter(":hidden");
          if (elem) {
            elem.filter(":first").fadeIn(2000);
          } else {
            clearInterval(secondInterval);
          }
        }, 5000);
      }, 60000);
    } else {
      $("#love p").filter(":hidden").filter(":first").fadeIn(2000);
      index++;
    }
  }, 5000);
});
```

First, your `var index = 0;` and looping until `index === 7` will run 8 times, rather than the intended 7. To fix this, change one of them to `var index = 1;` or `index === 6`.

Secondly, you create a new `timeout` every 5 seconds within the `firstInterval` code. You only want this to happen once the first 7 elements have been shown. This is fixed by moving it inside the `if (index === 7) {` statement so it will execute once 7 elements have been shown.

Another optimization I have applied is changing `$("#love p:hidden:first")` to `$("#love p").filter(":hidden").filter(":first")`. According to http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/:

> Because `:first` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:first` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. To achieve the best performance when using `:first` to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use `.filter(":first")`.

Changing `:hidden` is for the same reason. http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/.

Now everything works up to the first seven elements (assuming you have at least 7 elements, otherwise you will need to check for the existence of the element in the `else` within `firstIndex`). Next, we remove `clearTimeout(timeout);` as timeout's only run once and do not need to be cleared.

The next thing we do, is because we do not know how many elements there are to display after the first 7, we try to find a hidden element (with `var elem = $("#love p").filter(":hidden");`) and check for it's existence (using `if (elem)`). If it exists, we get the first one, and fade it in (`elem.filter(":first").fadeIn(2000);`), otherwise, we stop looping (`clearInterval(secondInterval);`).

Comment: Awesome. thanks. It works now. Can you share where the real difference between mine and yours and why mine doesn't work while yours work? For the benefit of others as well.